# How to use querying by date in Java Client Library?

Tags: java, gdata-java-client

I want to retrieve google documents that were uploaded after certain date using Java Client Library.
I use this code:

```
DocumentQuery query = new DocumentQuery(feedUri);
query.setPublishedMin(new DateTime(new Date().getTime()));
```

I get such exception:

```
com.google.gdata.util.ServiceForbiddenException: This service does not support the 'published-min' parameter.
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:593)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:563)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:550)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:530)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:535)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1135)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1077)
at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:662)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1034)
at ua.com.stormlabs.gap.gdocs.GDocumentsRetriever.getAllDocs(GDocumentsRetriever.java:84)
at ua.com.stormlabs.gap.gdocs.GDocsServiceProcessor.start(GDocsServiceProcessor.java:56)
at ua.com.stormlabs.gap.gdocs.GDocsGapApp.main(GDocsGapApp.java:21)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this feature doesn't work for Picasa.
http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=138

For some other services querying by date is working fine.